# what is the cin operator order in C++

Tags: c++

I have a question about cin and cout order in C++, for example:

```
int a,b;
std::string c;
std::cin >> a >> b >> c >> c >> a;
std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << " " << a;
```

if the input is "5 10 hello world 15 20", what is the output,
I can see the result, but can anyone explain me how it works?
cin assign 5 variable, but input is 6 values, and what is the order of cin and cout?

Comment: Did you try running it?

Comment: I do not understand how it works, it is not the matter of running, even I can see the result, I still need to confirm how it working

Comment: Perhaps you should amend your question to include the output you can see, and ask why it's not whatever it is you're expecting

Answer (score 7):

Output would be:

```
15 10 world 15
```

`std::cin` reads data into the first variable from the left first, and after that it  reads data into the second variable and so on.

```
std::cin >> a >> b >> c >> c >> a;
```

is equivalent to the following:

```
std::cin >> a; //reads 5
std::cin >> b; //reads 10
std::cin >> c; //reads hello
std::cin >> c; //reads world
std::cin >> a; //reads 15
```

See after reading `15`, it doesn't read the `20`, because there is no more `std::cin >> variable`.

Comment: input gives 6 values, but cin just assign 5 variables, what about the last value?

Comment: @cong: the last integer `20` isn't read.

Comment: @cong its lost because your program stop reading after the 5 value and std::cin is blocking execution until your press return.

Comment: @Lynch: It's not lost.  It's still there in the input stream, and the next call to `cin>>` will read it.

Answer (score 4):

C++ (ab)uses the shift operators for input and output. They are ***left-associative***, which means the left-most operator gets executed with its two operands, and the result of that form the left operand for the next operator. So something like

```
std::cin >> a >> b >> c >> c >> a;
```

essentially is interpreted as

```
((((std::cin >> a) >> b) >> c) >> c) >> a;
```

Let's look at this in detail. The expression `std::cin >> a` invokes

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, int& num);
```

That operator will read from `is` into `num` *and return (a reference to) `is`*. That is, the very same `is` object (`std::cin` in our case) is then used to read into `b`: `std::cin >> b`. This invokes the same operator, which reads into `b` and then again return it's left operand.
This, in turn, is used for reading into `c`. That is a string, so the operator invoked will be a bit different:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, std::string& str);
```

As you see, what differs from the previous overload is only the right operand (and the implementation, of course.) This, too, returns its left operand. (In fact, so do all input operator overloads, and so should ydo your own ones, too.)

Basically, your code is eqvivalent to this:

```
std::istream& tmp1 = std::cin >> a ;
std::istream& tmp2 = tmp1 >> b;
std::istream& tmp3 = tmp2 >> c;
std::istream& tmp4 = tmp3 >> c >> a;
```

---

For output, the situation is very similar, except that the output operators' signatures are slightl different:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, int num);
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::string& num);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are writing more than once to a variable between two sequence points, the output is undefined.
The `<<` operator is left-to right associative

Edit: Nonsense. Overloaded operators act like functions and so introduce sequence points. Tho output is like Nawaz wrote.